# Python3 - Openpyxl - For loop to search through Column - Gather information Based on position of first cell location

Tags: python-3.x, excel, for-loop, iteration, openpyxl

**UPDATE!**
My goal is to modify an existing Workbook ( example - master_v2.xlsm ) and produce a new workbook (Newclient4) based on the updates made to master_v2.
I'm using a single sheet within master_v2 to collect all the data which will be determining what the new workbook will be.

Currently using multiple if statements to find the value of the cells in this "repository" sheet. Based on specific cells, I'm creating and adding values to copies of an existing sheet called "PANDAS".

**My goal right now is to create a dict based on two columns. The loop through
the keys so that every time I get a hit on a cell, I will gather values from specific keys.**

That's listed below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Start by opening the spreadsheet and selecting the main sheet
workbook = load_workbook(filename="master_v2.xlsm",read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
DATASOURCE = workbook['repository']
DATASOURCE["A:H"]

cell100 = DATASOURCE["F6"].value
CREATION = cell100
cell101 = DATASOURCE["F135"].value
CREATION2 = cell101


cell107 = DATASOURCE["F780"].value
CREATION7 = cell107


if CREATION.isnumeric():
    source = workbook['PANDAS']
    target = workbook.copy_worksheet(source)
    ss_sheet = target
    ss_sheet.title = DATASOURCE['H4'].value[0:12]+' PANDAS'
    if CREATION2.isnumeric():
        source = workbook['PANDAS']
        target = workbook.copy_worksheet(source)
        ss_sheet = target
        ss_sheet.title = DATASOURCE['H133'].value[0:12]+' PANDAS'
        if CREATION3.isnumeric():
            source = workbook['PANDAS']
            target = workbook.copy_worksheet(source)
            ss_sheet = target
            ss_sheet.title = DATASOURCE['H262'].value[0:12]+' PANDAS'


else:
    print ("no")


workbook.save(filename="NewClient4.xlsm")
```

Instead of the many if statements I was hoping to be able to loop through the column as explained above,
once I found my value, gather data and copy it over to a copy of sheet which is then filled out by other cells. Each time the loop comples, I want to do repeat on the next match of the string.. but I'm only this far and it's not quite working.
Anyone have a way to get this working?

( trying to replace the many one to one mappings and if statements )

```
for i in range(1,3000):
    if DATASOURCE.cell(row=i,column=5).value == "Customer:":
        source = workbook['Design details']
        target = workbook.copy_worksheet(source)
        ss_sheet = target
        ss_sheet.title = DATASOURCE['H4'].value[0:12]+' Design details'

    else:
        print ("no")
```

Thank you guys in advanced

Comment: Can we have something shorter?

Comment: Charlie, thank you for a reply. Are you asking about the overall post? If it's in regards to the code, shorter is definitely what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Both code and and description. This looks like a simple task repeatedly endlessly and I don't have the patience to read it al.

Comment: Thank you Charlie for continuing to reply. I have updated the post. I appreciate all the feedback.